# how to disable special vulkan validation exception

Tags: exception, vulkan

I want to know how to disable a special exception thrown by the vulkan validation layers. Such as the exception that pipeline must need information of renderpass. Because I do not want to pass the parameters at that time, as well I promise I will use that pipeline in a suitable renderpass.

Answer (score 1):

The spec requires that you pass the renderpass because the implementation needs that information about the attachments in the renderpass it will be used.

You can instead make a compatible dummy renderpass to pass to it.

Comment: Got it. But does the implementation really need that information? Since it work well when pass a null to it. By the way, how does compatible renderpass works? It it only depend on that special subpass?

Comment: @TKWei: "*Since it work well when pass a null to it.*" Undefined behavior is *undefined*. Just because something appears to work doesn't mean it does. Vulkan is not a *safe* API; that's why we have validation layers. "*how does compatible renderpass works?*" The details are in the Vulkan specification.

Comment: Clear. I will check the specification.

Comment: Most importantly, many of the requirements (including this one) are things that *some* implementations (hardware + driver) need, but others don't. So the ones that don't need it will work fine on your computer if you don't provide it .. but your app won't work when someone runs it on a different computer. Some implementations definitely do need this information.

Answer (score 1):

In the general sense, there isn't a way to modify the layers on such a small scale. [The `vk_layer_settings.txt` file](https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanSamples/blob/master/layers/vk_layer_settings.txt)  (located in the `VK_LAYER_SETTINGS_PATH` directory) gives you a number of configuration options, but they tend to be "per-layer" rather than "per-error message".

You might be able to use the `VK_EXT_debug_report` to filter specific errors.

> Such as the exception that pipeline must need information of renderpass. Because I do not want to pass the parameters at that time, as well I promise I will use that pipeline in a suitable renderpass.

I'm not *quite* sure what you mean by that.

Providing a `VkRenderPass` at the time a pipeline is constructed is *not optional* in Vulkan. The specification requires that you provide one, so there's no way to create a pipeline without a renderpass.

However, you are not required to use that exact `VkRenderPass` object later on; just one that is compatible with it. Nor are you required to keep the original `VkRenderPass` object around after you create the pipeline.

However, the problem you may have is an issue where some implementations don't do this right, partially because the spec was slightly unclear on this. This is [a known spec bug which will be fixed](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/516), and a test will be added to the test suite to catch implementations that break it. And validation layers will need to be changed (assuming they're not already working right) to adapt.

So if that's your problem, you'll just kind of have to work around it for now.

Comment: Thanks for your warn-hearted answer. I think I will use a dummy renderpass to do that. But I don't know if swapchain attachment can be compatible with normal attachment. If not, there will be a lot of renderpasses needed, since someone needs clearing, someone don't.

Comment: @TKWei: `VkAttachmentDescription` doesn't specify images; it specifies image *formats*.

Comment: My swapchain format is B8G8R8A8, it seem to be compatible with R8G8B8A8(result is fine). If this is also a undefined behavior?

Comment: @TKWei: "*result is fine*" Stop using that to justify things. The Vulkan specification is not that hard to read, and the section on renderpass compatibility is not particularly difficult to find. It's also not particularly hard to just copy the swap chain image's format directly in your renderpass object.

Comment: Yes sir, I will do that.